# Mounts denied: EOF with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, macos-catalina

I'm using Docker Compose to run some code, but when I run `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: Mounts denied: EOF
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

The only mounts are relative and just to check I added the project folder under file sharing in Docker settings. Here's a relevant section in `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
volumes:
  - .:/opt/app:delegated
  - .npm_cache:/root/.npm
  - .yarn-cache:/root/.yarn-cache
  - node_modules:/opt/app/node_modules
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? I was able to run the same project earlier on a different computer but I'm not sure what's different about this environment.

Comment: docker usually expects volumes to have a direct path. you may want to change the source mount points for npm cache, yarn cache, and node_modules. assuming these are all on the normal spot on the machine. `~/.npm_cache`, `~/.yarn-cache`, and `./node_modules` respectively.